# Как проверить огромный массив объектов без for

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

Делая игру на node js столкнулся с долгой обработкой объектов. В массиве свыше 700 объектов, как можно проверять каждый, не тормозя сервер? То-есть чем можно заменить этот кусок кода, чтобы не было зависаний, если эта функция выполняется каждые 13 миллисекунд?

GIF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AdPq.jpg (Синяя полоска это направление игрока, должен следовать за курсором.)

GIF (10 объектов на карте): https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0msO.jpg (Зависания только из за записи)

```
function update() {
    for (var name in objects) {
        objectC = objects[name];
        if (objectC.canmove == 1) {
            if (objectC.mY == 0 && objectC.mX == 0) {
                objectC.mY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) -5;
                objectC.mX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) -5;
            }
            if (objectC.speed == 0) {
                objectC.speed = Math.random();
            }
            speedObj = objectC.speed || config.movspeed / 3;
            var objAngle = Math.atan2(objectC.mY, objectC.mX);
            var objDist = Math.sqrt(sq(objectC.mX) + sq(objectC.mY));
            objectC.anglez = angle(0, 0, objectC.mX, objectC.mY);
            speed = Math.min(speedObj, 0.035 * Math.pow(objDist, impImitz));
            if (speed < 0.06 && speed > -0.06) { speed = 0 }
            objectC.vx = speed * Math.cos(objAngle);
            objectC.vy = speed * Math.sin(objAngle);
            objectC.x += objectC.vx;
            objectC.y += objectC.vy;
        }
        if (objectC.x <= config.leftBorder || objectC.x-objectC.size <= config.leftBorder) {
            objectC.x = config.rightBorder - objectC.size - 25;
        } else if (objectC.x >= config.rightBorder || objectC.x+objectC.size >= config.rightBorder - 25) {
            objectC.x = config.leftBorder + objectC.size + 25;
        }
        if (objectC.y <= config.upBorder || objectC.y-objectC.size <= config.upBorder) {
            objectC.y = config.downBorder - objectC.size - 25;
        } else if (objectC.y >= config.downBorder || objectC.y+objectC.size >= config.downBorder - 25) {
            objectC.y = config.upBorder + objectC.size + 25;
        }
        if (objectC.angle >= 360) {
            objectC.angle = 0;
        }
        objectC.angle += objectC.speedZ;
        objectC.size = objectC.mass / 2;
    }
    for (var name in players) {
        var playerCheck = players[name];
        var playerCheckMouse = gameMouse[name];
        if (playerCheck.spectator == 1) {
            playerCheck.x += playerCheck.spectatorspeedx;
            playerCheck.y += playerCheck.spectatorspeedy;
            playerCheck.name = "";
            if (playerCheck.x <= config.leftBorder) {
                playerCheck.spectatorspeedx = 3;
            } else if (playerCheck.x >= config.rightBorder) {
                playerCheck.spectatorspeedx = -3;
            }
            if (playerCheck.y <= config.upBorder) {
                playerCheck.spectatorspeedy = 3;
            } else if (playerCheck.y >= config.downBorder) {
                playerCheck.spectatorspeedy = -3;
            }
        }
        if (playerCheck.spectator == 0) {
            if (playerCheck.hp <= 0) {
                playerCheck.spectator = 1;
                playerCheck.hp = 100;
                playerCheck.h = 100;
                playerCheck.mass = playerCheck.mass / 2;
                setSysmsg("You're dead! Watch your health!", playerCheck.clientid);
            } else {
                if (playerCheck.abilitycooldown > 0) {
                    playerCheck.abilitycooldown -= 1;
                }
                playerCheck.mX = playerCheckMouse.x;
                playerCheck.mY = playerCheckMouse.y;
                speedPlr = playerCheck.speed || config.movspeed;
                var mouseAngle = Math.atan2(playerCheck.mY, playerCheck.mX);
                var mouseDist = Math.sqrt(sq(playerCheck.mX) + sq(playerCheck.mY));
                playerCheck.angle = angle(0, 0, playerCheck.mX, playerCheck.mY);
                speed = Math.min(speedPlr, 0.035 * Math.pow(mouseDist, impImitz));
                if (speed < 0.06 && speed > -0.06) { speed = 0 }
                playerCheck.vx = speed * Math.cos(mouseAngle);
                playerCheck.vy = speed * Math.sin(mouseAngle);
                playerCheck.x += playerCheck.vx;
                playerCheck.y += playerCheck.vy;
                if (playerCheck.x <= config.leftBorder || playerCheck.x-playerCheck.size <= config.leftBorder) {
                    playerCheck.x = config.rightBorder - playerCheck.size - 25;
                } else if (playerCheck.x >= config.rightBorder || playerCheck.x+playerCheck.size >= config.rightBorder - 25) {
                    playerCheck.x = config.leftBorder + playerCheck.size + 25;
                }
                if (playerCheck.y <= config.upBorder || playerCheck.y-playerCheck.size <= config.upBorder) {
                    playerCheck.y = config.downBorder - playerCheck.size - 25;
                } else if (playerCheck.y >= config.downBorder || playerCheck.y+playerCheck.size >= config.downBorder - 25) {
                    playerCheck.y = config.upBorder + playerCheck.size + 25;
                }
                for (var objid in objects) {
                    objectZ = objects[objid];
                    if (playerCheck.y+(playerCheck.size-5) + 2 * Math.PI > objectZ.y && playerCheck.y-(playerCheck.size-5) - 2 * Math.PI < objectZ.y && playerCheck.x+(playerCheck.size-5) + 2 * Math.PI > objectZ.x && playerCheck.x-(playerCheck.size-5) - 2 * Math.PI < objectZ.x) {
                        if (objectZ.type == "asteroid") {
                            foodCount--;
                            playerCheck.mass += Number(objectZ.mass / 2);
                            playerCheck.h += Number(objectZ.mass / 2);
                            delete objects[objid];
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (playerCheck.mass > playerCheck.xpToUpgrade) {
                    playerCheck.size = playerCheck.xpToUpgrade / 5;
                } else {
                    playerCheck.size = playerCheck.mass / 5;
                }
                if (playerCheck.size < 25) {
                    playerCheck.size = 15;
                } 
                playerCheck.camzoom = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
setInterval(update, 13);
```

node --prof-process

```
Statistical profiling result from isolate-v8.log, (16475 ticks, 3 unaccounted, 0 excluded).

 [Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
  13297   80.7%          ..\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
   3087   18.7%          ..\nodejs\node.exe
      9    0.1%          ..\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
      6    0.0%          ..\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
      1    0.0%          ..\system32\WS2_32.dll

 [JavaScript]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
     36    0.2%   48.0%  LazyCompile: *update ..\index.js:35:20
     10    0.1%   13.3%  LazyCompile: *processTimers internal/timers.js:477:25
      6    0.0%    8.0%  LazyCompile: *listOnTimeout internal/timers.js:497:25
      5    0.0%    6.7%  LazyCompile: *Writable.write _stream_writable.js:289:36
      3    0.0%    4.0%  LazyCompile: *validateAsyncId internal/async_hooks.js:120:25
      2    0.0%    2.7%  LazyCompile: *draw ..\index.js:498:17
      2    0.0%    2.7%  LazyCompile: *_copy buffer.js:192:15
      2    0.0%    2.7%  LazyCompile: *WebSocketFrame.toBuffer ..\node_modules\websocket\lib\WebSocketFrame.js:174:45
      1    0.0%    1.3%  LazyCompile: *toInteger buffer.js:182:19
      1    0.0%    1.3%  LazyCompile: *resolve path.js:130:10
      1    0.0%    1.3%  LazyCompile: *pushAsyncIds internal/async_hooks.js:404:22
      1    0.0%    1.3%  LazyCompile: *percolateDown internal/priority_queue.js:49:16
      1    0.0%    1.3%  LazyCompile: *normalizeString path.js:52:25
      1    0.0%    1.3%  LazyCompile: *debug ..\node_modules\debug\src\debug.js:65:17

 [C++]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name

 [Summary]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
     72    0.4%   96.0%  JavaScript
      0    0.0%    0.0%  C++
     45    0.3%   60.0%  GC
  16400   99.5%          Shared libraries
      3    0.0%          Unaccounted

 [C++ entry points]:
   ticks    cpp   total   name

 [Bottom up (heavy) profile]:
  Note: percentage shows a share of a particular caller in the total
  amount of its parent calls.
  Callers occupying less than 1.0% are not shown.

   ticks parent  name
  13297   80.7%  ..\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

   3087   18.7%  ..\nodejs\node.exe
   2474   80.1%    ..\nodejs\node.exe
   2063   83.4%      LazyCompile: *draw ..\index.js:498:17
   1392   67.5%        LazyCompile: *processTimers internal/timers.js:477:25
    671   32.5%        LazyCompile: *listOnTimeout internal/timers.js:497:25
    671  100.0%          LazyCompile: *processTimers internal/timers.js:477:25
     78    3.2%      LazyCompile: ~draw ..\index.js:498:17
     50    2.0%      LazyCompile: *update ..\index.js:35:20
     26   52.0%        LazyCompile: *processTimers internal/timers.js:477:25
     12   24.0%        LazyCompile: ~listOnTimeout internal/timers.js:497:25
      8   66.7%          LazyCompile: ~processTimers internal/timers.js:477:25
      4   33.3%          LazyCompile: *processTimers internal/timers.js:477:25
     12   24.0%        LazyCompile: *listOnTimeout internal/timers.js:497:25
     12  100.0%          LazyCompile: *processTimers internal/timers.js:477:25
     45    1.8%      LazyCompile: *_copy buffer.js:192:15
     45  100.0%        LazyCompile: *WebSocketFrame.toBuffer ..\node_modules\websocket\lib\WebSocketFrame.js:174:45
     45  100.0%          LazyCompile: *draw ..\index.js:498:17
     30   66.7%            LazyCompile: *processTimers internal/timers.js:477:25
     15   33.3%            LazyCompile: *listOnTimeout internal/timers.js:497:25
     27    1.1%      LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
     25   92.6%        LazyCompile: ~nativeModuleRequire internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:299:29
      2    8.0%          LazyCompile: ~initializeCJSLoader internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:395:29
      2  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~prepareMainThreadExecution internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:14:36
      2    8.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/bootstrap/node.js:1:1
      2    8.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> http.js:1:1
      2  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          LazyCompile: ~setupPrepareStackTrace internal/bootstrap/node.js:251:32
      1  100.0%            Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/bootstrap/node.js:1:1
      1    4.0%          LazyCompile: ~setupBuffer internal/bootstrap/node.js:329:21
      1  100.0%            Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/bootstrap/node.js:1:1
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> tty.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> tls.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> stream.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/util/inspect.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/url.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/timers.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/source_map/source_map_cache.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/cluster/master.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> fs.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> events.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> crypto.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> cluster.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> buffer.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> _stream_readable.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      1    4.0%          Eval: ~<anonymous> _http_common.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:266:27
      2    7.4%        LazyCompile: ~compileForPublicLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:213:25
      2  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~loadNativeModule internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:26
      2  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~Module._load internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:845:24
     39    1.3%    LazyCompile: *processTimers internal/timers.js:477:25
     33    1.1%    LazyCompile: *update ..\index.js:35:20
     21   63.6%      LazyCompile: *processTimers internal/timers.js:477:25
      7   21.2%      LazyCompile: ~listOnTimeout internal/timers.js:497:25
      6   85.7%        LazyCompile: *processTimers internal/timers.js:477:25
      1   14.3%        LazyCompile: ~processTimers internal/timers.js:477:25
      5   15.2%      LazyCompile: *listOnTimeout internal/timers.js:497:25
      5  100.0%        LazyCompile: *processTimers internal/timers.js:477:25
```

Comment: А в чем состоит сама проверка? .

Comment: И потом - саму функцию можно же сделать асинхронной.  Проверку - оптимизировать алгоритмически. Но вы не привели никакого кода, кроме того, что есть цикл. А 700 объектов это не огромной массив, а  очень маленький. Огромный это от миллиона....

Comment: Этот кусок кода ничем заменить нельзя, т.к. нет кода :)

Comment: Я про то чем можно заменить цикл for, оптимизировать его, так как на передвижение игрока (смену направления) уходит около 10 секунд.

Comment: Изменил код, написал весь.

Comment: Как его можно оптимизировать?

Comment: Смотря сколько параметров в объекте.

Comment: А чем обусловлен выбор цикла `for (... in ...)` вместо `for (... of ...)` для итерирования массива? Не то, что бы это влияло на скорость, просто интересно.

Comment: @Yaant Мне просто так удобнее.

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые соображения, которые, возможно, не помогут.

1. Попробуйте [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) вместо [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) — `for...in` каждый раз просматривает, нет ли наследуемых перечисляемых свойств во всей цепочке прототипов.
2. Подумайте, нельзя ли обойтись без удаления свойств объектов — это обычно замедляет работу с объектами. Также проверьте, как вы создаёте объекты — задавать сразу все свойства в литерале может быть эффективнее, чем добавлять свойства объекту после создания.

Про оптимизацию работы с объектами можно почитать тут (можно не вникать в детали, просто запомнить практические рекомендации, которые там даются):

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shapes-ics (то же тут: https://benediktmeurer.de/2018/06/14/javascript-engine-fundamentals-shapes-and-inline-caches/)

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/prototypes (то же тут: https://benediktmeurer.de/2018/08/16/javascript-engine-fundamentals-optimizing-prototypes/)

https://v8.dev/blog/react-cliff

Comment: Нет, не помогло :(

Comment: @lksmnd Ну, у вас много математики. Возможно, там нет бутылочного горлышка и функция объективно сложная. Но можно попробовать профилировать и посмотреть, нет ли каких функций, которые занимают больше всего времени, и тогда уже думать над их заменой. Если никогда не профилировали, начните с этих трёх статей:  https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/ , https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/ , https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/diagnostics-flamegraph/

Comment: Через профилирование я и нашел эту функцию.